# observable object in an Activity Diagram?

Tags: android-activity, uml, diagram

How can I draw an activity diagram for this use case below?

> User opens a closeable window to view a live update of xyz-data.

Specifically, I want to show an object flow in an [activity diagram](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_activitydiagram.html), but the object is an
observable data-storage object (i.e., the GUI control is bound to this data and thus shows a
live view of the data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still an object isn't it? You can either mark it by a special class (i.e. `:ObservableDataStorage`) or a Stereotype or Keyword (i.e. `<<Observable>> : DataStorage`). Or/and you can use a relation which is named "observes" between the observer and the observable.